Installing any new plugin gradle error displaying in react native android studio and the build failed
gradle error script 'PATH\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 401
App working with no problem with existing Dependency, but When i install any new plugin / Dependency this Gradle error shows kindly help me to resolve.
my package.json consists of
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.6",
yarn add @react-native-community/datetimepicker@7.0.1 this is the plugin i added.

have you solved this? i've been looking everywhere for a fix for this. btw do you also get this error with that one?


Working with the existing Dependency not installed any new plugin. thank you for your support.
